# Exporting data to excel using javascript under following constraint

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have a project on exporting data to excel using JavaScript. But the constraints are : It should work for all browsers unlike `ActiveXObject`(that works only for Internet Explorer), window.open(that doesn't works for internet explorer).

It should not depend on other applications like `Flash` (I have seen a code using `jQuery` and `Flash`, but I can't use that in my project) e.t.c.

Please tell me whether it is possible and if it is, then suggest me a method to do this...

And one more thing, Manual work shouldn't be there or if it is, then it should be very less. In other words, it should be completely automated.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- use CSV file format and write a CSV writer in JavaScript yourself
- use Microsoft's Office Open XML file format (xlsx) and write JavaScript code that generates such a file (should not be too difficult as it is XML based and there should be a lot of code around generating XML in JavaScript)

Comment: Could you please elaborate these points - especially second one, I didn't get what do you want to say? Actually, I am very new for these topics...